# Scala Lift - Cloudbees 500 error, mongo record

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift, cloudbees

I have a perfectly fine, running version of my app both locally, and within a dedicated server environment.

I am now in the process of hosting the service through the cloud alone, but have run into an odd error that I would very much appreciate some help with.

The error in question results from a new record being created for this model:

```
    class Panel_Model private() extends MongoRecord[Panel_Model] with ObjectIdPk[Panel_Model] {

    def meta = Panel_Model

    object dbid extends LongField(this)
    object handle extends StringField(this, 50)
    object room extends StringField(this, 50)
    object user extends StringField(this, 50)
    object name extends StringField(this, 50)
    object element extends StringField(this, 50)

    object slide extends MongoJsonObjectListField(this, Panel_Model_Slide)

    object state extends JsonObjectField(this, Panel_Model_State) {
        def defaultValue = null.asInstanceOf[Panel_Model_State]
    }

    object time extends JsonObjectField(this, Panel_Model_Time) {
        def defaultValue = null.asInstanceOf[Panel_Model_Time]
    }

}


object Panel_Model extends Panel_Model with MongoMetaRecord[Panel_Model] {
    override def collectionName = "panels"
}


case class Panel_Model_Slide (

    handle: String,
    media: String,
    param: Map[String, String],
    content: String,
    view: String,
    index: Int,
    active: Int

) extends JsonObject[Panel_Model_Slide] {
     def meta = Panel_Model_Slide
}


object Panel_Model_Slide extends JsonObjectMeta[Panel_Model_Slide]


case class Panel_Model_State (

    ready: Int,
    active: Int,
    locked: Int,
    slide: Map[String, Int]

) extends JsonObject[Panel_Model_State] {
    def meta = Panel_Model_State
}


object Panel_Model_State extends JsonObjectMeta[Panel_Model_State]


case class Panel_Model_Time (

    created: Long

) extends JsonObject[Panel_Model_Time] {
    def meta = Panel_Model_Time
}


object Panel_Model_Time extends JsonObjectMeta[Panel_Model_Time]
```

And the actual call that produces the error, only within the cloudbees environment is this:

```
Panel_Model.createRecord.
dbid(dbid).
room(Room_Session.is).
user(User_Session.is).
name(fph.fileName).
handle(handle).
element(element).
state(Panel_Model_State(

    0, active, 0, Map(

    ("active" -> 1),
    ("total" -> 1)

)

)).
time(Panel_Model_Time(unix)).
save
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at the error in the log (bees app:tail, or the web console) to see what the actual error happening is.

bees app:tail -a yourAppId - and looking at the result when it is in the error state - that would help a lot.

Comment: I've noticed you work for cloudbees, desperately trying to find some kind of direct contact but to no avail, would very much like to re-imburse you for a few moments of your time to isolate this issue given you're perfectly positioned to help in this matter, and finally get us using your awesome service and ditch ye olde dedicated server. Not sure how to proceed but please let me know an appropriate channel to get in touch. All the best and many thanks for taking the time to get in touch :)

Comment: P.S: Tried adding you on LinkedIn to no avail, would very much appreciate a few moments of your valuable time, please get in touch :)

Comment: If you can get on IRC - #cloudbees on irc.cloudbees.com - ping miclorb (me).

Comment: can never find you on irc, could you email @ sirjamm[at]gmail[dt]com. Thanks